# What CSS rules would I need to put in place to make the provided DIVS equal heights relative to their container elements?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am using flexbox to align a group of items in a Bootstrap which allows each row to have equal heights. Currently utilizing  `display:flex` to each row and each item, all of the item heights are equal except for individual content areas ie, divs, inside of these item containers. Is there a solution for this so that each contact div is equal height instead of each person div?

Adding flexbox to each row and person div adds extra padding under the contact div area: 
[image: Flexbox added]

I would like these areas to be of equal height:
[image: Need Equal Heights]

=== HTML (Using Angular) ===

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="staff" >
<h1>Who We Are</h1>
<div class="col-sm-12" id="staff">
<div class="row" ng-repeat="peoples in chunkedData()">
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-center person" ng-repeat="people in peoples">
        <div class="person--border">
        <img src="{{people.img}}">
        <div class="content">
            <h4>{{people.name}}</h4>
            <h5>{{people.title}}</h5>
            <p>{{people.bio}}</p>
        </div>
            <div class="contact">
                <a href="mailto:{{people.email}}" ng-if="people.email"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a>
                <a href="tel:{{people.phone}}" ng-if="people.phone"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span></a>
                <a href="{{people.linkedin}}" ng-if="people.linkedin"><span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

=== CSS ===

```
.row { display: flex;  }
.person { display: flex; }
```

I've also tried the below without success:

```
.person { display: flex; }
.person .content { content-align: flex; display: flex; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox won't make non-sibling elements the same height.

Although setting `display:flex` on the `row` will all the children the same height you still have to tell each 'person' to be a column and then assign flex-directions and flex properties to make the columns fill the respective parents.

Plus you are fighting against Bootstrap's normal layout so some of the classes need to be doubled up.

I have assumed that all the images are the same height and that the icon divs will also be the same height. So the "content" div can just be expanded to take up any remaining height.

```
.row {
  display: flex; /* all the persons ar ethe same height */
}

.col-sm-3.person {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* each person is now a column */
}

.col-sm-3.person .person--border {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* inner div also a column */
  flex:1; /* and 100% high */
  border:1px solid grey;
}

.col-sm-3.person .content {
  flex:1; /* make this element expand to fill all remaining space */
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.col-sm-3.person {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.col-sm-3.person .person--border {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  bordeR: 1px solid grey;
}
.col-sm-3.person .content {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-sm-12" id="staff">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-3 text-center person">

      <div class="person--border">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/people-q-c-250-250-10.jpg">

        <div class="content">
          <h4>Name</h4>
          <h5>Title</h5>
          <p>Bio: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="contact">
          <a href="mailto:{{people.email}}" ng-if="people.email"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a>
          <a href="tel:{{people.phone}}" ng-if="people.phone"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span></a>
          <a href="{{people.linkedin}}" ng-if="people.linkedin"><span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span></a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 text-center person">

      <div class="person--border">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/people-q-c-250-250-10.jpg">

        <div class="content">
          <h4>Name</h4>
          <h5>Title</h5>
          <p>Bio: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, sit.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="contact">
          <a href="mailto:{{people.email}}" ng-if="people.email"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a>
          <a href="tel:{{people.phone}}" ng-if="people.phone"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span></a>
          <a href="{{people.linkedin}}" ng-if="people.linkedin"><span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span></a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 text-center person">

      <div class="person--border">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/people-q-c-250-250-10.jpg">

        <div class="content">
          <h4>Name</h4>
          <h5>Title</h5>
          <p>Bio: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="contact">
          <a href="mailto:{{people.email}}" ng-if="people.email"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a>
          <a href="tel:{{people.phone}}" ng-if="people.phone"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span></a>
          <a href="{{people.linkedin}}" ng-if="people.linkedin"><span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span></a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 text-center person">

      <div class="person--border">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/people-q-c-250-250-10.jpg">

        <div class="content">
          <h4>Name</h4>
          <h5>Title</h5>
          <p>Bio: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci, sit.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="contact">
          <a href="mailto:{{people.email}}" ng-if="people.email"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a>
          <a href="tel:{{people.phone}}" ng-if="people.phone"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span></a>
          <a href="{{people.linkedin}}" ng-if="people.linkedin"><span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span></a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 text-center person">

      <div class="person--border">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/image_output/people-q-c-250-250-10.jpg">

        <div class="content">
          <h4>Name</h4>
          <h5>Title</h5>
          <p>Bio: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="contact">
          <a href="mailto:{{people.email}}" ng-if="people.email"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a>
          <a href="tel:{{people.phone}}" ng-if="people.phone"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span></a>
          <a href="{{people.linkedin}}" ng-if="people.linkedin"><span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span></a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/JYgZRR)